# xcscope key rebinding in in conflict with emacs default

Tags: emacs

I have the following in my init.el but c-\ in emacs binds to input method. I don't use input method anyways so is there a way to disable c-\ not to bind to input method?

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d")

(require 'xcscope)

(setq cscope-do-not-update-database t)

(define-key cscope:map "\C-\\s" 'cscope-find-this-symbol)

(define-key cscope:map "\C-\\g" 'cscope-find-global-definition)

(define-key cscope:map "\C-\\d" 'cscope-find-called-functions)

(define-key cscope:map "\C-\\c" 'cscope-find-functions-calling-this-function)

(define-key cscope:map "\C-\\t" 'cscope-find-this-text-string)

(define-key cscope:map "\C-\\e" 'cscope-find-egrep-pattern)

(define-key cscope:map "\C-\\f" 'cscope-find-this-file)

(define-key cscope:map "\C-\\i" 'cscope-find-files-including-file)

(define-key cscope:map "\C-\\b" 'cscope-display-buffer)

(define-key cscope:map "\C-\\B" 'cscope-display-buffer-toggle)

(define-key cscope:map "\C-\\n" 'cscope-next-symbol)

(define-key cscope:map "\C-\\N" 'cscope-next-file)

(define-key cscope:map "\C-\\p" 'cscope-prev-symbol)

(define-key cscope:map "\C-\\P" 'cscope-prev-file)

(define-key cscope:map "\C-\\u" 'cscope-pop-mark)

(define-key cscope:map "\C-\\v" 'cscope-history-backward)

(define-key cscope:map "\C-\\V" 'cscope-history-forward)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`(global-unset-key (kbd "C-\\"))`